# Handlebars JS: How to display URL parameter values on page

Tags: javascript, handlebars.js

Is it possible to use Handlebars.js to access URL parameter values and display them on the current page?

For example, I have a page with URL `pageName?id=12345&price=1250`.
I would like to display the `id` and `price` values on the page. Is there a way to access these values using Handlebars?

Something like:

```
<td>Id: {{id value goes here}}</td>
<td>Price: {{price value goes here}}</td>
```

Comment: Handlebars is just a templating  engine . To access URL values  you should use JS and then pass extracted values to your template.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `registerHelper` to search your URL for the parameter value and return it for template.

```js
Handlebars.registerHelper('getParam', function(param) {
    const url = new URL("https://www.example.com/pageName?id=12345&price=1250");
    return url.searchParams.get(param);
});

var t = Handlebars.compile($('#t').html());
$('body').append(t({
    id: "id",
    price: "price"
}));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/handlebars.js/4.1.2/handlebars.min.js"></script>
<script id="t" type="text/x-handlebars">
  <p>Id: {{getParam id}}</p>
  <p>Price: {{getParam price}}</p>
</script>
```